# Magento browse files button not working

Tags: image, file, magento, upload, image-uploading

**Magento Upload Image Issue** : When I click on "Browse Files" button to upload images for a product. It is not browsing files from my computer.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try different browsers. I know sometimes I find, say, it won't work in Chrome but will in Firefox. It's all Flash related.

Answer (score 2):

Magentos Flex uploader is based on Flash. If you cannot select files this usually means you don't have the Flash plugin activated in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Check that there are no javascript errors

You can use chrome developer console.
Basically to start using it just open website in chrome, right click on certain element and select "inspect element".
After that switch to console tab and reload the page.
More about it can be found here - https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console