# Magento wysiwyg image uploader not working

Tags: magento, wysiwyg, image-uploading, image-upload

I get the message "directory not writable" when trying to upload images into a normal cms page.

I have seen this before so I created a wysiwyg folder inside the media folder and chmod it to 777.

The images now upload but they dont appear in the wysiwyg folder on the backend. So I cant pick any images to inset into a page.

I tried copying the js folder from the original install folder, and it still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It's not entirely clear from your description and I suspect you're not seeing this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160622/magento-browse-files-button-not-working/26164189#26164189 but just in case have you tried a different browser?

Comment: Sorry, didnt understand how stackoverflow works.

So the folder exists and its chmod is 777. The files upload fine the image folder that pops up after clicking the tree icon is empty tho.

Not sure how to fix it?

I have magento running over 6 other sites with no problems.

Comment: permissions are a pain on magento. I created a script that I run any time permissions are at question. At a bare minimum you want to probably chmod -R [webserveruser].[webservergroup] the magento directory whenever you encounter them with rare exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Check whether there is a folder named **wysiwyg** in **media** folder.

If no, then create /media/wysiwyg folder in magento installation folder and chmod 777.

If the problem still persists, then open the site in Firefox browser and activate firebug while opening the site.

Click on **console** and reload the page.

Now try to upload image. If there is some js error in console of browser, then download same version of magento you have, and replace the js folder from the download into your Magento installation and come back to minification later on.

**Note:** create a backup of your current js folder, just in case. Delete it once you have confirmed the fix works.

Comment: Thanks, I already had the wysiwyg folder and chmod it to 777.

Comment: Yes thank you, tried those and no luck.

I put the firebug error in my answer above. Let me know if that helps?